# no known conversion from 'ofxEdsdk::Camera' to 'cv::Mat &' #53

Tags: opencv, openframeworks, edsdk

I'm stuck trying yo get a cv::Mat format from the camera Cannon Mark II image.

I am using OpenFramework. 
[edsdk addon](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxEdsdk)

The basic example from ofxEdsdk works, but when I try to use it inside a project for FaceTracking I can't apply the [`toCv()`](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxCv#tocv-and-copy) method,  throw the error 'No matching function for call to 'toCv'

The code works with a webcam, but doesn't with the camera, I think the key to solve this problem is in this sentence from Xcode:

**'Candidate function not viable: no known conversion from 'ofxEdsdk::Camera' to 'cv::Mat &' for 1st argument**

Is kinda obvious the error is there but I just can't solve this! I'v been trying for weeks!. I hope some of you could help me.

Comment: Can't help you if you don't show us a [mcve] that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Here it basically tells you that you have a function, which takes a cv::Mat as first argument and you pass an ofxEdsdk::Camera variable. There is no implicit conversion for this, thus the crash. You should add part of your code to see what can be wrong. But my guess is that you are passing the camera variable and not the image variable to the function.